# Can an order be filled but uncommitted?

Tags: equities

Let's say I place an order to buy shares. Let's says uncommitted shares are those not actively working with other destinations or brokers, and committed shares are those actively working but yet unfilled with other destinations or 
brokers.

Can my order be filled and yet uncommitted? If yes, how?